# SQL select subquery IN from table column values

Tags: sql, postgresql

First, apologize for maybe not being able to express the title of the question properly, I am not very much into SQL queries.

I have a table "parkings" with columns like this

```
| days_2        | from_hr   | to_hr
"1,2,3,4,5"     "08:00:00"  "18:00:00"
"0,1,2,3,4,5,6" "08:00:00"  "22:00:00"
...
...
```

I made a next query which is working OK:

```
SELECT Extract(dow from current_timestamp::DATE) as Day, 
    current_time BETWEEN from_hr and to_hr as ParkHour, 
    days_2, 
    from_hr, 
    to_hr  
FROM public.parkings;
```

If today is Monday and current time is 21:26:00 results is:

```
day | ParkHour  | days_2        | from_hr   | to_hr
1    f          "1,2,3,4,5"     "08:00:00"  "18:00:00"
1    t          "0,1,2,3,4,5,6" "08:00:00"  "22:00:00"
...
...
```

I would like to modify this query in a way that in the first column will be stored result (true/false) if current day number is in table column **days_2** for that record , in a way like this

```
SELECT Extract(dow from current_timestamp::DATE)  in (1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

where if it's now sunday (0) for example the final results will be false for first row but true in the second row:

```
day | ParkHour  | days_2        | from_hr   | to_hr
 f   f          "1,2,3,4,5"     "08:00:00"  "18:00:00"
 t   t          "0,1,2,3,4,5,6"  "08:00:00" "22:00:00"
```

How can I accomplish this ?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with relational databases, the days_2 column should be normalised to contain a single value - so your first row would become five rows. Once you know what you're doing, you can use an SQL99 ARRAY data type for it and use the UNNEST function in your query.

Comment: what database are you using? SQL Server. Oracle ...?

Comment: Postgresql. I put tags on question

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    extract(dow from now())
    =
    any (regexp_split_to_array('1,2,3', ',')::integer[]);
 ?column? 
----------
 t
```

Turning that column type to array would avoid the string spliting step.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select 
  case
    when Extract(dow from current_timestamp::DATE) = '0' then 't' else 'f'
    when Extract(dow from current_timestamp::DATE) = '1' then 't' else 'f'
    when Extract(dow from current_timestamp::DATE) = '2' then 't' else 'f'
    when Extract(dow from current_timestamp::DATE) = '3' then 't' else 'f'
    when Extract(dow from current_timestamp::DATE) = '4' then 't' else 'f'
    when Extract(dow from current_timestamp::DATE) = '5' then 't' else 'f'
    when Extract(dow from current_timestamp::DATE) = '6' then 't' else 'f'
  end as day,
  current_time BETWEEN from_hr and to_hr as ParkHour, 
  days_2, 
  from_hr, 
  to_hr  
from public.parkings;
```

As others have mentioned, it would easier if your table structure was better and / or if you used an array.

HTH